# Drupal Load Balancing

Tags: php, drupal, load-balancing

So we have a drupal 6 website that is running good, but now we want to prepare it for a *lot* of traffic, so the next step is to have 2 web servers running the same site (the database is already running on a separate server) and then use a another server to do the load balancing between those 2.

So yesterday i mirrored the files of the original drupal server (that runs at lets say www.example.com) to the new server (that runs at lets say 123.123.123.123 - just an IP, no domain), than i edited the settings.php file of the second one to make sure that the base url is 123.123.123.123.

once i browsed to 123.123.123.123 to test out if the mirror of the site was working, i got a blank page.. looking at the source, the basic structure was there, but no content, and the CSS was pointing to the right place but still not showing.. I decided to browse to 123.123.123.123/admin/ and see what i could do.. went to the site performance and cleared the cache, didn't do a thing but then i noticed the original drupal was now showing blank... so i went to www.example.com/admin/, cleared the cache also, site was back, but it appeared the menu router was destroyed because i was getting "page not found" everywhere. So i went to the modules page and clicked save hopping that it would rebuild the menu router. It did the trick, site was back online and working good.

Obviously i stopped poking around with 123.123.123.123 and decided it was time to ask for some help from the experts...

What am i doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Julien

Comment: If your load balancing is set up to be fully transparent, you must not change the base url on the second machine. example.com points to your load balancer and he forwards the request to any of your servers. Each of them should use example.com to build URLs for links and resources. Then if the client requests those URLs, it hits the load balancer again.  Maybe you need sticky sessions and probably the files folder (where uploads are saved) shared between all servers (NFS).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Regarding the folder for uploaded files, its already on a NAS that is mounted on both servers so no problem there. the load balancer is not setup yet, for now i just wanted to test a mirrored copy of my drupal site to see if it was working and go on from there.. point is i get no content at all.. I mean, both servers have the same files and same configs, what is causing that one is not retrieving the content and why would it mess with the menu router...?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that out of the box you can do this with D6.

There are a couple of things which will catch you out.

- Settings are stored in the database so if your servers are not identical one server will not work.
- The database is not set up to work with more than one server accessing it. This could cause race conditions or deadlocks.
- Uploaded or generated files will not be mirrored on both servers so files will be missing.

Probably other things too but this is enough to be going on with.

So you have two options:

- Go with something like pressflow which is D6 compatible and has options for working on mirrored servers.
- Configure your server to handle the load.

Configuring your server may be a good starting point. Here are some tips

- make sure Drupal caching is turned on
- Use an optcode cache like apc, see some benchmarks [here](http://2bits.com/articles/benchmarking-drupal-with-php-op-code-caches-apc-eaccelerator-and-xcache-compared.html)
- Install cache router module to use apc for Drupal's cache
- install Boost module

There is a much more in depth article [here](http://cruncht.com/75/drupal-performance-scalability)

I would suggest reading the article and doing everything you can on one server. While it is possible to go to 2 or even 200 servers it adds a lot of complexity to your system.

Comment: thanks for the reply, u did forgot the link the to article though... ;)